# How are sentences of this form called in mathematical logic and where to find more about them?

Tags: logic

It is an easy task to prove with the method of mathematical induction, that, for example, this holds:

$1+2+...+n= \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}$

It is also easy to prove that this holds:

$1+2+...+2^{n-1}=2^n - 1$

There are also, as you know, other statements of similar form that are more or less easy to prove by induction.

The examples that I have in mind are of the form(as are above mentioned two examples): "$\forall n \in \mathbb N$ we have $a(n)=b(n)$"

So, in these and similar examples we just prove that two sequences ($a(n),b(n)$) are exactly the same sequence.

> How are sentences of the form "$\forall n \in \mathbb N$ we have $a(n)=b(n)$" called? Where to find more about them? You can suppose that $a(n),b(n) \in \mathbb N$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ if that helps?

Comment: Theorems regarding sequences involving natural numbers? Elementary number theory?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are thinking of, but if a formula $\psi$ is equivalent to $\forall n\phi$ where $\phi$ has only bounded quantifiers, then $\psi$ is $\Pi_1$ in the arithmetical hierarchy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy

Comment: @Szmagpie: It is true but totally non-obvious that the sentence about powers of 2 is a $Δ_0$-sentence! Even the weaker fact that it can be expressed in the language of arithmetic (as opposed to the language of EFA; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_arithmetic) is the crux of Godel's proof of the incompleteness theorems.